# How can I show specific years in Google Timeline Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization

Using react-google-charts, I would like to specify which years should be displayed on the horizontal axis of a Google Timeline Chart. The screenshot shows an example that uses automatically generated values, based on the given time range of the rows.

The example uses the following data:

```
[
  [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
  [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
  [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
]
```

[image: Timeline Chart Example with automatically generated years on horizontal axis]

I already tried the following options with no joy:

```
hAxis: {
    title: 'Year',
    minValue: new Date(1785, 3, 15),
    maxValue: new Date(1825, 3, 15),
    ticks: [
      { v: new Date(1792, 3, 15), f: '1792' },
      { v: new Date(1818, 3, 15), f: '1818' },
      { v: new Date(1824, 3, 15), f: '1824' }
    ]
}
```

I would expect to have the x-Axis labelled with "Years" and showing 1792, 1818 and 1824 instead of 1790 and 1800.
The minValue and maxValue options seem to get ignored, too.

According to the [readme](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts) it should be working.

Is the problem related to the value being date-objects instead of integers?

**Edit:** Added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4zg7mxt/
It is not using react-google-charts, but the problem remains the same: ticks (and title) options still have no effect. Interestingly, the minValue and maxValue options are taken into account though.
Is it possible at all to adapt the jsfiddle, in order to show the specified years on the horizontal axis?

Comment: option simply isn't available on Timeline charts...

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't explicitly say so in the docs (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes). Also, it's strange that minValue and maxValue will not work with react-google-charts, but it is working in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: fairly certain, obviously doesn't work, see answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found if the configuration option, or other feature, isn't listed on the guide for that particular chart,
the chart doesn't support it.

*except* for options added in more recent releases,
in which the guide for that chart hasn't been updated.

as such, the only `hAxis` options available on a Timeline chart are `minValue` and `maxValue`

made available with the [October 2, 2015 release](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#october-2-2015)

> **Timeline:**
>   -- Durations are now localized.
>   -- Now supports `minValue` and `maxValue` for the horizontal axis.

Comment: the most frustrating missing feature on the timeline chart is `setSelection` -- i have a _hack_ if you need to set a default selection

Comment: Thanks, but I think I will move on with victory charts instead, since it is impossible to set specific ticks on google's timeline.

Answer (score 0):

The library automatically calculates the scaling of x-axis based on the start date, end date and browser's display area.
Please paste full code, will check and update you whether it is possible to do the custom scaling of the x-axis.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle example to my question. Here - without react-google-charts - it is possible to set the start end end of the x-axis using minValue and maxValue. However, the question is actually about showing specific years instead of the automatically generated ones. Can you get the "ticks" option to work in the jsfiddle?